# How to set a jqueryui datepicker minDate after initialization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two datepickers (jqueryui) and I would like to restrict the second inputs (minDate property) to the value selected in first. How should I do this? I wrote the following code, without success:

```
  $("#picker1").button().click(function() {
        var minDate = $( "#picker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        $( "#picker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", minDate );  
        $( "#picker2" ).datepicker( "refresh");  
        });
```

Can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several days after, what worket for me was:

```
$("#picker1").datepicker({
    onClose: function(selectedDate){
     $("#picker2").datepicker("option", "minDate",selectedDate);
    }
});
```

retrieved from: [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Answers until this date didn't worked. Answer from @Arun P Johny worked fine in Fiddle, but not in my system (I don't know why).

Comment: To be clear, this is the exact section of the API documentation that this is from: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
$('#p1, #p2').datepicker();

$('#p1').change(function(){
    $('#p2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#p1').datepicker('getDate'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9j5BV/)

Comment: very good. It's exactly what I want. But I'm not achieving to do the same in my JSP, where I'm using jquery to manipulate the component's behavior. Have you any idea/tip on what should I do to reach the same goal? Thank you for responding!

Comment: In case you are using jQuery UI 1.8, note that the 'option' method wasn't introduced until jQuery UI 1.9

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `getDate` returning string .You can try like this.

```
$("#picker1").button().click(function() {
        var minDate = $( "#picker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" );      
        $( "#picker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",  new Date(minDate));  
        $( "#picker2" ).datepicker( "refresh");  
        });
```