# jQuery datepicker - how to override initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using in my project a global initialization of [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker) - it's pretty much this code:

```
$('body').find(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

For certain pages, though, I need to override this global definition and need to (re-)init `datepicker` with this setup:

```
jQuery(function() {     
        var date = new Date();
        var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
        var currentDate = date.getDate();
        var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth-3, currentDate),
            maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth+3, currentDate)
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the second block of code (with `minDate` and `maxDate`) is never "executed" - the original initialization of `datepicker` is not overriden.

One solution to this problem is to rename all `.datepicker` classes to, say, `datepicker2`. However, on the page is 12 inputs with this class I need to do this page change on 3 pages, so it's changing like 40 input classes.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not skip the global init on those three pages?

Comment: I am having the datepicker on automatically generated pages, where using `datepicker`s is mandatory, so that's the reason fo the global init. The 3 pages are exception where I need to "skip" the original init.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a jqueryui datepicker minDate after initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481326/how-to-set-a-jqueryui-datepicker-mindate-after-initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to destroy it before you can `re-init` it.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker('destroy');
```

Example

```
jQuery(function() {     
        var date = new Date();
        var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
        var currentDate = date.getDate();
        var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy'); //Destroy it before re-initing
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth-3, currentDate),
            maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth+3, currentDate)
        });
    });
```

The other option (as you mentioned) is to cherry pick those datepickers that need the one-off configuration.